# Filter listview with edittext and spinner

Tags: android, listview, filter

I have a list that contains information of a database, and this information can filter it by the family of products with a marker, until here everything is fine, but I need to put a search engine to make the search more expeditious (for that reason I wanted to place an editext that was filtering)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you to search the list

### If you want to search directly from data base the put query inside loop

```
edPeopleSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, 
                   int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            edPeopleSearch.setCursorVisible(true);
            if (list != null) {
                s = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                final ArrayList<PagePeopleModel> filter_list = new ArrayList<PagePeopleModel>();

                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                    final String text = list.get(i).getFirst_name().toLowerCase() + list.get(i).getLast_name().toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains(s)) {

                        filter_list.add(list.get(i));
                    }
                }

                adapter = new PagePeopleAdapter(activity, filter_list);
                resViewPeopleCode.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    imgPagePeopleClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    imgPagePeopleClose.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```